# How do i run a color detection algorithm on a point cloud in jupyter?

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter, point-clouds, color-detection

i am doing a final year project on a color detection on a point cloud (.ply) file. Currently, i am able to run the color detection codes through a livefeed (webcam), and also able to open and display my point cloud from the local file in my desktop. However, i was not able to make the color detection to work on the point cloud.

My codes are as shown below:

```py
import numpy as np

import open3d as o3d

import cv2

while(1):

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        pcd = o3d.io.read_point_cloud(r"C:\Users\frenz\Desktop\DJI 2402\pointcloud welded object 240220.ply")  #import and read from local file
        o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([pcd])                                                               #display point cloud
        print(pcd)                                                                                             #show amount of points on point cloud

    xyz_load = np.asarray(pcd.points)
    print('xyz_load')
    print(xyz_load)

    _, PointCloud = pcd.read()

    #defining the range of red color
    red_lower=np.array([136,87,111],np.uint8)
    red_upper=np.array([180,255,255],np.uint8)
    #defining the Range of Blue color
    blue_lower=np.array([99,115,150],np.uint8)
    blue_upper=np.array([110,255,255],np.uint8)

    #defining the Range of yellow color
    yellow_lower=np.array([22,60,200],np.uint8)
    yellow_upper=np.array([60,255,255],np.uint8)
    #finding the range of red,blue and yellow color in the image
    red=cv2.inRange(hsv, red_lower, red_upper)
    blue=cv2.inRange(hsv,blue_lower,blue_upper)
    yellow=cv2.inRange(hsv,yellow_lower,yellow_upper)

    #Morphological transformation, Dilation  
    kernal = np.ones((5 ,5), "uint8")
    red=cv2.dilate(red, kernal)
    res=cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask = red)
    blue=cv2.dilate(blue,kernal)
    res1=cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask = blue)
    yellow=cv2.dilate(yellow,kernal)
    res2=cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask = yellow)    
    #Tracking the Red Color
    (contours,hierarchy)=cv2.findContours(red,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    for pic, contour in enumerate(contours):
            area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
            if(area>300):
                    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
                    img = cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,0,255),2)
                    cv2.putText(img,"RED color",(x,y),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0,0,255))
    #Tracking the Blue Color
    (contours,hierarchy)=cv2.findContours(blue,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    for pic, contour in enumerate(contours):
            area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
            if(area>300):
                    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
                    img = cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
                    cv2.putText(img,"Blue color",(x,y),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (255,0,0))
    #Tracking the yellow Color
    (contours,hierarchy)=cv2.findContours(yellow,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    for pic, contour in enumerate(contours):
            area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
            if(area>300):
                    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
                    img = cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)
                    cv2.putText(img,"yellow  color",(x,y),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1.0, (0,255,0))  


    #cv2.imshow("Redcolour",red)
    cv2.imshow("Color Tracking",img)
    #cv2.imshow("red",res)  
    if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            cap.release()
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break
```

```py
Attribute error: 'open3d.open3d.geometry.PointCloud' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Any suggestions on how i could continue to make this work? Looking forward to any advices.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: if `PointCloud` doesn't have `read()` then why you use `pcd.read()` ?